Azure Function with Bicep: Deploy Completes Successfully, But Function URL Returns 500 Error
I'm deploying an Azure Function using Bicep and Azure Pipelines. Both the infrastructure deployment and the pipeline execution complete successfully. However, when I navigate to the Azure Function in the portal, I see my test API listed as expected. But when I try to retrieve the API URL (the one with the function code), Azure returns a 500 Internal Server Error.

Additionally, I noticed an inconsistency with the deployment: although the function is linked to a storage account and deployed using zip deployment, the storage account's container doesn't contain the expected metadata or artifacts. This doesn't align with what I would expect from a typical function deployment.
Below are the relevant files for the setup:
main.bicep
@description('The environment for the function to be deployed in')
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'stg'
  'prd'
])
param env string = 'dev'

@description('Location for all resources unless otherwise specified.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('The instance number for the current function to be deployed')
@minLength(2)
@maxLength(2)
param instance string = '01'

@description('VPN IP address for firewall rule')
param vpnIpAddress string

@description('Location for Log Analytics Workspace')
param logAnalyticsLocation string = 'westeurope'

@description('Group ID for developers to assign roles')
param devGroupId string

@description('The project name')
@minLength(4)
param projectName string

@description('The name of the Virtual Network')
param vnetName string

@description('The name of the subnet for the storage account')
param storageSubnetName string = 'storage-subnet'

@description('The name of the subnet for the function app')
param functionSubnetName string

@description('The resource group of the VNet')
param vnetResourceGroup string

@description('The App Registration (Service Principal) ID for the pipeline service connection')
param serviceConnectionObjectId string

var resourceGroupTags = resourceGroup().tags

module logAnalyticsWorkspace './modules/log_analytics_workspace.bicep' = {
  name: 'logAnalyticsDeployment'
  params: {
    projectName: projectName
    location: logAnalyticsLocation
    env: env
    devGroupId: devGroupId
    tags: resourceGroupTags
  }
}

module function './modules/function.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionDeployment'
  params: {
    projectName: projectName
    env: env
    instance: instance
    location: location
    vpnIpAddress: vpnIpAddress
    logAnalyticsWorkspaceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.outputs.logAnalyticsId
    devGroupId: devGroupId
    tags: resourceGroupTags
    vnetName: vnetName
    storageSubnetName: storageSubnetName
    vnetResourceGroup: vnetResourceGroup
    functionSubnetName: functionSubnetName
    serviceConnectionObjectId: serviceConnectionObjectId
  }
}

function.bicep
@description('The name of the project')
@minLength(4)
param projectName string

@description('The environment for the function to be deployed in')
param env string

@description('The instance number for the function')
@minLength(2)
@maxLength(2)
param instance string

@description('Location for the resources')
param location string

@description('VPN IP address for firewall rule')
param vpnIpAddress string

@description('Log Analytics Workspace ID for monitoring')
param logAnalyticsWorkspaceId string

@description('Group ID for developers')
param devGroupId string

@description('Tags to associate with resources')
param tags object

@description('The Virtual Network name')
param vnetName string

@description('The subnet for the storage account')
param storageSubnetName string

@description('The resource group of the VNet')
param vnetResourceGroup string

@description('The name of the subnet for the function app')
param functionSubnetName string = 'storage-subnet'

@description('The App Registration (Service Principal) ID for the pipeline service connection')
param serviceConnectionObjectId string

var functionAppName = '${projectName}-${env}-${instance}-func'
var hostingPlanName = 'ASP-${projectName}-${env}-${instance}'
var storageAccountName = toLower('${projectName}${env}${instance}funcst')
var applicationInsightsName = '${projectName}-${env}-${instance}-insights'

@description('Variables that change based on the environment')
var envSpecifics = {
  dev: {
    storageAccountType: 'Standard_LRS'
    hostingPlanSkuSpecs: {
      name: 'Y1'
      tier: 'Dynamic'
    }
  }
  stg: {
    storageAccountType: 'Standard_GRS'
    hostingPlanSkuSpecs: {
      name: 'P2V2'
      tier: 'PremiumV2'
    }
  }
  prd: {
    storageAccountType: 'Standard_RAGRS'
    hostingPlanSkuSpecs: {
      name: 'P2V2'
      tier: 'PremiumV2'
    }
  }
}

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspaceId
  }
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: envSpecifics[env].storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: resourceId(vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, functionSubnetName)
        }
        {
          id: resourceId(vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, storageSubnetName)
        }
      ]
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
    }
  }
  tags: tags
}

resource storageAccountRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, devGroupId, 'Storage Blob Data Contributor')
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
      'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',
      'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe'
    )
    principalId: devGroupId
    principalType: 'Group'
  }
  scope: storageAccount
}

resource serviceConnectionRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, serviceConnectionObjectId, 'Contributor')
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
      'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions',
      'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
    )
    principalId: serviceConnectionObjectId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
  scope: storageAccount
}

resource storagePrivateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2021-08-01' = {
  name: '${storageAccountName}-private-endpoint'
  location: location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: resourceId(vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, storageSubnetName)
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: '${storageAccountName}-connection'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: storageAccount.id
          groupIds: [
            'blob'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: envSpecifics[env].hostingPlanSkuSpecs.name
    tier: envSpecifics[env].hostingPlanSkuSpecs.tier
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  tags: tags
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    storageAccountRequired: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'python|3.10'
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'python'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_ALWAYS_ON'
          value: 'true'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE'
          value: 'true'
        }
        {
          name: 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT'
          value: 'true'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};Authentication=Managed Identity'
        }
      ]
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: true
    }
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: resourceId(
      vnetResourceGroup,
      'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',
      vnetName,
      functionSubnetName
    )
    httpsOnly: true
  }
  tags: tags
}

resource privateDnsZoneBlob 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2018-09-01' = {
  name: 'privatelink.blob.core.windows.net'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {}
}

resource privateDnsZoneFile 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones@2018-09-01' = {
  name: 'privatelink.file.core.windows.net'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {}
}

resource dnsZoneVnetLinkBlob 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks@2018-09-01' = {
  name: '${privateDnsZoneBlob.name}/${vnetName}-link'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    virtualNetwork: {
      id: resourceId(vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', vnetName)
    }
    registrationEnabled: false
  }
}

resource dnsZoneVnetLinkFile 'Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/virtualNetworkLinks@2018-09-01' = {
  name: '${privateDnsZoneFile.name}/${vnetName}-link'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    virtualNetwork: {
      id: resourceId(vnetResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', vnetName)
    }
    registrationEnabled: false
  }
}

resource storagePrivateDnsZoneGroup 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups@2020-03-01' = {
  name: '${storagePrivateEndpoint.name}/default'
  properties: {
    privateDnsZoneConfigs: [
      {
        name: 'blob-dns-zone-config'
        properties: {
          privateDnsZoneId: privateDnsZoneBlob

What I've tried:
Tested Storage Account Connectivity: I ran nslookup and curl from the Kudu console to check if the Azure Function could reach the storage account. Everything seems fine; the storage account is reachable without any issues.
Quadruple-Checked App Settings: I went through the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string in the function's app settings multiple times. It’s set up correctly, using managed identity authentication like this:
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<obfuscated-name>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;Authentication=Managed Identity. I also tried without managed identity.
Checked Storage Account for Deployment Artifacts: After deploying, I looked into the blob container of the storage account, expecting to see some metadata or deployment files, but it’s completely empty. It’s like the deployment isn’t registering anything there.
Tried a Direct Deployment: To rule out any issues with the pipeline, I deployed the function directly using the Azure CLI. Same result—500 error when trying to get the URL of the function, and the storage account still doesn’t have any deployment data.
Reviewed Infrastructure Configs: I went over all the Bicep files I’m using to deploy the infrastructure to make sure there’s nothing off in how the storage account, function app, or permissions are set up. I didn’t find anything obviously wrong.
Checked Managed Identity Setup: I confirmed that the Function App’s managed identity has the correct Storage Blob Data Contributor role assigned to the storage account. Permissions seem fine.

Have you looked at the Log Stream of the function, that might give you more error details?

Since you've eliminated Azure Pipelines as a culprit, there's no reason to add the pipeline information or tag the question with azure-pipelines. It's unrelated to the problem.

Have you tried adding dependson block and verified? @wolfguyminifigure
